# Upgrading to Win 8 on a computer with windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 on my laptop, where I had installed Ubuntu alongside Windows.  Now, I would like to, if I can, upgrade to Windows 8 without any formatting.  How would that affect the booting process? Would it cause any problems with Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I can't respond you how to upgrade Windows, but I can tell you that *may be* this procedure will modify the **MBR**, in such case you will need to [repair the GRUB](http://askubuntu.com/q/134794/62483)

Answer (score 0):

If you UPGRADE your windows, it will not be problem. What I experienced about windows 7 to 8 installation is this:

You can upgrade Windows 7 32-bit to Windows 8 32-bit only. -32-bit to 64-bit is not possible in upgrade process.
-You have to buy a saperate DVD to go from 32-bit to 64-bit.

This UPGRADE should not modify MBR and you will be able to keep Ubuntu as it is.